# Freemarker - pass param to nested macros

Tags: macros, freemarker

Let's say I have two macros, one is nested in other one.

```
[#macro testNestingTOP id]
   [#nested]
[/#macro]

[#macro testNesting]
   id: ${id}
[/#macro]
```

---

**Usage**:

How can I retrieve value of id param from **testNesting** macros?

```
[@testNestingTOP id='SOME VALUE']
  [@testNesting /]
[/@testNestingTOP]
```

Answer (score 0):

add attribute to your inner macro and pass the id as a value to it

```
[@testNesting innerID ]
//code
[@testNesting /]

[@testNestingTOP id='SOME VALUE']
   //code
  [@testNesting innerID=id/]
  //code
[/@testNestingTOP]
```

I wish this could help